# How to change a a photo that has been uploaded. PHP

Tags: php

Im very sorry if this has been answered before but I have been looking Google for a while and have not found answer.

My problem

I have uploaded a file using PHP for my site. I want to be ale to give the user the option to change the image they have uploaded. I managed to do it when they could only upload 1 image but now im trying to add more. they can add more than one photo but when it comes to changing them im having a problem.

here was my code for 1 image (which works)

```
$newname = "$pid.jpg";
move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'], "../inventory_images/$newname");
header("location: inventory_list.php"); 
exit();
```

This is the code I used to change it.

```
    if ($_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'] != "") {
    // Place image in the folder 
    $newname = "$pid.jpg";
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'], "../inventory_images/$newname");
}
header("location: inventory_list.php");
```

This is what I have now changed the code to for multiple images.

```
$image1 = "$pid Image1.jpg";
$image2 = "$pid Image2.jpg";
$image3 = "$pid Image3.jpg";
$image4 = "$pid Image4.jpg";
$image5 = "$pid Image5.jpg";
move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'], "../inventory_images/$image1");
move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'], "../inventory_images/$image2");
move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'], "../inventory_images/$image3");
move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'], "../inventory_images/$image4");
move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'], "../inventory_images/$image5");
header("location: inventory_list.php");
```

This is what I have tried but I know there is a logical error in if

```
    if ($_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'] != "") {
    // Place image in the folder 
$image1 = "$pid Image1.jpg";
$image2 = "$pid Image2.jpg";
$image3 = "$pid Image3.jpg";
$image4 = "$pid Image4.jpg";
$image5 = "$pid Image5.jpg";
move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'], "../inventory_images/$image1");
move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'], "../inventory_images/$image2");
move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'], "../inventory_images/$image3");
move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'], "../inventory_images/$image4");
move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'], "../inventory_images/$image5");
}
```

And this is part of my form

```
      <tr>
  <td align="right">Product Image: 1</td>
  <td><div class="single">
    <a href="../inventory_images/<?php echo $id; ?> Image1.jpg" rel="lightbox" title="<?php echo $product_name; ?>"><img src="../inventory_images/<?php echo $id; ?> Image1.jpg" width="142" height="188" alt="<?php echo $product_name; ?>" /></a>
</div></td> 
  </tr>
        <tr>
    <td align="right"></td>
    <td><label>
      <input type="file" name="Image1" id="Image1" />
    </label></td>
  </tr>
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Sorry $pid is the product id. To relate the products to the images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_FILES['fileField']` won't contain your image since your input's name is `Image1`.
You have to use `$_FILES['Image1']`.
But as Mouloud suggested, it is easier to use an array insted and then loop over it. But if you want to give each image-input a unique name that will also work.

Here is how I would do it:

HTML:

```
<input type="file" name="image[1]" id="Image1" />
<input type="file" name="image[2]" id="Image2" />
<input type="file" name="image[3]" id="Image3" />
...
```

PHP:

```
foreach($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] as $i => $tmpName) {
    if ($tmpName){
        move_uploaded_file( $tmpName, "../inventory_images/{$pid}Image{$i}.jpg");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is a much cleaner way of doing it!

Comment: I have uploaded the files using this way now. How would I go about give the user the option to change any one of them with out having to change all of them?

Comment: @Will What do you mean by changing? Do you want to offer the user an option to replace some files with new ones?

Comment: @Will I've updated my answer. This code should work for both creating and replacing. The index given in the html (eg. image[**1**]) is the reference in the php-code

Answer (score 1):

the input file field must be like this for multiple file upload (exemple):

```
<input type="file" name="Images[]" id="Image1" />
```

in multiple file upload the $_FILE array have this format :

```
$_FILES['Images']['name'][0] // first file name
$_FILES['Images']['tmp_name'][0] // first file tmp_name
```

also see the max_file_uploads configuration directive

this will helpe you : http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php

ps: in the link above see the first comment by **Donatas Olseviius** :
he give a fix to $_FILE array.

Comment: It should be $_FILES['Images'] to match with your html